# mvvmcross 4.0.0.beta5 setup fails with "could not load plugin assembly for type MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser.PluginLoader"

Tags: plugins, mvvmcross, uwp

I am porting a Windows Store app built with MvvmCross to UWP, and I am working my way through a number of issues. The latest is with the PictureChooser plugin which fails to load and throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I am having the same problem as others did with the Email plugin a month or so back, but with the PictureChooser plugin. One of the solutions proposed for the Email plugin pointed me in the right direction, but there were some issues. First, there is no override for 'LoadPlugins' in MvxWindowsSetup. Instead, I tried the following changes to setup.cs:

```
using MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser;
using MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser.WindowsStore;
using Cirrious.CrossCore.Plugins;

. . .

protected override IMvxPluginManager CreatePluginManager()
{
    Mvx.RegisterType<IMvxPictureChooserTask, MvxPictureChooserTask>();
    return base.CreatePluginManager();
}
```

Note, there was no 'WindowsCommon' namespace for PictureChooser, so I used 'WindowsStore' which was present as the result of the nugget package install. I then excluded the PictureChooserPluginLoader and I was able to proceed. Looks like there is a namespace issue in the 4.0.0.0-beta5 version of the PictureChooser plugin.